# Facebook App fails in Chrome

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome

I'm trying to view a FB App but it fails with the next error:

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL https://www.facebook.com/dialog/ from frame with URL URL. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

What can I do to solve it? This happens **only in Chrome**.

I deleted some of the info from the error, which is not necessary.

Comment: Is your application running on https ?

Comment: No it doesn't, does it have to?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/497/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is the problem with SSL

See : https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/497/

for

Today, we are announcing an update to our Developer Roadmap that outlines a plan requiring all sites and apps to migrate to OAuth 2.0, process the signed_request parameter, and obtain an SSL certificate by October 1.